# Jquery Ui Auto complete filter local JSON Array

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im pulling down a local json array and storing it when my page loads, however my results dont seem to filter?
Any ideas?

```
var invoiceList= @Html.Raw(
        Json.Encode(
            ((IEnumerable<Invoice>)Model.InvoiceList)
            .Select(inv=> new
            {
                Id = inv.Id,
                Amount= inv.Amount
            })
        )
    );
```

Html Result:

```
  var invoiceList= [{"Id":"8da2786f-8f3d-496e-81eb-12be330cb67a","Amount":"100.00"},{"Id":"2D5A84EB-B146-43EE-8D28-8801F9F02027","Amount":"150.00"}];
```

HTML:

```
<input id="project" onkeydown="InvoiceSearch(this);">
<script>
 function InvoiceSearch(elemt) {
        var id = $(elemt).attr('id');
        var searchTerm = $(elemt).val();
        $("#project").autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.Amount);
                return false;
            },
            source: invoiceList,

                select: function(event, ui)
                {
                    $("#project").val(ui.item.Amount);
                    return false; 
                }
        }).autocomplete( "instance" )
            ._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                console.log(item);
                return $( "<li>" )
                  .append( "<div>" + item.Amount+ "<br></div>" )
                  .appendTo( ul );
            };
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to name mappings,
it wants a label and value, I was using a Id and Amount for my naming, so renamed my json results to label and value.

```
var invoiceList= [{"value":"8da2786f-8f3d-496e-81eb-12be330cb67a","label":"100.00"},{"value":"2D5A84EB-B146-43EE-8D28-8801F9F02027","label":"150.00"}];
```

Hope this helps anyone else.